# Webview is displaying its content below the main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

i have created a webview for my android application , inicially i am tying to take application simpler as possible to understand things . i have created a webview to display the different page in it . i simply created a button which load url into webview which is working perfectly fine ,but the webview is loading the urls below the button . it is not overriding the main layout or not opening the url in newpage. i see the webpage in webview and the button above it . how can get rid of this button. thanks in advance. here is my java and xml code

**activity**

```
public class TestinglinkActivity extends Activity {
     final Activity activity = this;
     WebView webview;

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;


        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });


    Button btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_login);
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.pk");
             webview.goBack();
             webview.goForward();

          }
         }
     );


           }




}
```

**xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"  
        android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
        >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_click_login"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="GO"/>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="4"

        />
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

         />

</RelativeLayout>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="4"

        />

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to start a new Activity when the button is pressed. The reason your WebView appears below the other layout is because that's exactly what your XML describes. If you want your WebView to appear full screen, you need to move the WebView to a separate Activity which is started when your button is clicked.

You probably will want to pass the URL in the Extra of the Intent used to start the new Activity.

Comment: no , i dont want to start the new activity , i just want to display the webview on the whole screen , when i remove the scrolvillview , it works perfectly fine.i dont know why it is not working with the scrollview.

Comment: Maybe you should want to start a new activity though! Your XML defines all the elements, so it's correct that they don't magically disappear. If you really want to stick with a single activity, you could call `btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in your OnClickListener and do the same for any other views you want to disappear. You'll need to make btn_login final or use another method of making it visible from within the OnClickListener.

Comment: Remember that your WebView's layout_height="fill_parent" is ignored in a ScrollView as it would be meaningless as a ScrollView is effectively of infinite height. That's why it's different in a ScrollView.